# XBee S1 communication issue

Tags: java, c++, embedded, xbee

I have 2 XBee S1 modules configured in API mode 1. XBee module 1 is a transmitter of a signal and XBee module 2 is a receiver of a signal. And the issue is that receiver does not receives anything from transmitter (or so it seems).

Transmitter configuration is this:

```
AP 1
MY 1
ID 1984
DL 2
CH C
```

Everything else is left by default.
Transmitter is attached to XBee Explorer. XBee Explorer is connected to PC via USB.

Following piece of code sends signal each 1 second:

```java
public class Main {

    private Main() {
        XBee xbee = new XBee();
        try {
            xbee.open("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600);
            final XBeeRequest request = new TxRequest16(new XBeeAddress16(0, 2), new int[] { 1 });

            //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement
            while (true) {
                xbee.sendSynchronous(request);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            xbee.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Java XBee API library was used: https://code.google.com/p/xbee-api/
And I see TX LED flashing every second.

Receiver configuration is this:

```
AP 1
MY 2
ID 1984
DL 1
CH C
```

Everything else is left by default.
Following wiring for receiver is used:
[image]

Receiver is attached to the breadboard via XBee Explorer. Continuity test shows that current flows fine between XBee RX and mbed P27, as well as between XBee TX and mbed P28.

And following code on an mbed (LPC1768) runs to receive packets:

```cpp
Serial terminal(USBTX, USBRX);

while(1) {
    terminal.puts("Reading packet...\r\n");
    xbee.readPacketUntilAvailable();
    terminal.puts("Packet available\r\n");

    XBeeResponse response = xbee.getResponse();
    if (response.isAvailable()) {
        char tmp[20];
        sprintf(tmp, "0x%02X", response.getApiId());
        terminal.puts("Response available at API: ");
        terminal.puts(tmp);
        terminal.puts("\r\n");
        uint8_t api = response.getApiId();
        if (api == RX_16_RESPONSE) {
            Rx16Response rx16 = Rx16Response();
            response.getRx16Response(rx16);
            uint8_t len = rx16.getDataLength();
            char l[20];
            sprintf(l, "%d", len);

            terminal.puts("We have data: ");
            terminal.puts(l);
            terminal.puts("\r\n");
        }
    }
    wait(1);
}
```

Popular Arduino/mbed library for an XBee API mode was used. Sources are located here: http://mbed.org/users/okini3939/code/XBee/

And the output of a console is: `Reading packet...` for all times.
And RX LED is not flashing on receiver.

Comment: can you connect both to the PC?

Comment: the other think to make sure of is they are both on the same channel

Comment: @KeithNicholas Receiver does not have USB connector. Only transmitter does. As for the same channel, triplet consisting of MY, ID and DL are the only options that need to be set. They are set correctly (as per documentation).

One other detail is that if embedded solution will start sending packets and PC will start listening (i.e. if I swap transmitter and receiver), then everything goes well.

Comment: both are receivers and transmitters, and the xbee can operate on multiple channels, I use them for talking to various things and tend to set them on different channels to avoid interference

Comment: @KeithNicholas I see. Thank you. I'll check CH option.

Comment: @KeithNicholas I have updated my question with channel option value. They share the same channel, C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was complex (consisted with a few smaller issues). Dumping request and response frames from both ends as @tomlogic suggested was quite helpful.

To resolve these issues I first ensured that hardware part works.

XBee explorer has 4 LEDs. One is power and should always glow red when powered. And 3 others, depending on what explorer you have, may be called `rx, tx, rssi` or `din, dout, rssi`.

When transmitting code runs, we first need to make sure that `rx` and `tx` are blinking simultaneously every second. I.e. signal is sent each second.

When receiving code runs and calls `readPacketUntilAvailable`, LEDs on receiving XBee explorer should glow as follows: `rssi` glows constantly, `tx` or `dout` should blink.

Now that when we know hardware is fine, we can debug software part.

My issue was with receiving code. When we are setting up receiving XBee, we need to make sure we do two things. First, we call `xbee.begin(baudRate)`. And second, we should reset module.

```
reset = 0;
wait_ms(100);
reset = 1;
wait_ms(100);
```

And last, but not least thing, `readPacketUntilAvailable` method will **not** reset response. We call this function in a loop. Whatever first response we get will be repeated, no matter what other data is sent by transmitter.

First response that receiver got in my case was `MODEM_STATUS_RESPONSE` (**0x8A** in HEX). And subsequent packets were not read. `readPacket` must be called instead, since that method will reset previous response.

My receiving code now looks like this:

```java
XBee xbee(p28, p27);
DigitalOut reset(p11);
DigitalOut mbed_led1(LED1);

int main() {
    Serial terminal(USBTX, USBRX);
    while(!terminal.readable()) {
        wait_ms(10);
    }
    terminal.getc();
    mbed_led1 = 1;
    xbee.begin(9600);
    reset = 0;
    wait_ms(100);
    reset = 1;
    wait_ms(100);

    while(1) {
        terminal.puts("Reading packet...\r\n");
        xbee.readPacket(500);
        XBeeResponse response = xbee.getResponse();
        if (response.isAvailable()) {
            terminal.puts("Packet available\r\n");
            XBeeResponse response = xbee.getResponse();

            char tmp[20];
            sprintf(tmp, "0x%02X", response.getApiId());
            terminal.puts("Response available at API: ");
            terminal.puts(tmp);
            terminal.puts("\r\n");
            uint8_t api = response.getApiId();
            if (api == RX_16_RESPONSE) {
                Rx16Response rx16 = Rx16Response();
                response.getRx16Response(rx16);
                uint8_t len = rx16.getDataLength();
                char l[20];
                sprintf(l, "%d", len);

                terminal.puts("We have data of length ");
                terminal.puts(l);
                terminal.puts("\r\n");
            }
        }

        wait(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have a duplicated call `XBeeResponse response = xbee.getResponse();` both outside and inside of your `if (response.isAvailable())`.

Comment: @tomlogic Indeed, I missed that bit :) Fortunately, getResponse is a plain getter that returns private variable stored by successfull readPacket execution. And thus does not cause any harm.

Answer (score 0):

Note that because you're running in API mode, `ATDL` isn't used so you shouldn't need to set it.

The Java library you linked to is documented as only working with `ATAP=2`.  Try changing that setting on the transmitting node.

You should be dumping any packets that come in on the transmitter.  The XBee module should generate a "Transmit Status" (0x89) frame that can aid in debugging.

Comment: It didn't work. Although, it was a great tip and I appreciate it. What I have now after I did all your suggested fixes is this (raw response packet):

[0x0, 0x3, 0x89, 0x1, 0x1, 0x74]

I.e. I changed API mode to 2 and dumped response as you suggested.

Comment: I am not sure if I read this packet properly, but it looks like after frame ID I have status 1, which is "An expected MAC acknowledgement never occurred."?

Comment: @oddy, is it possible to dump the outbound request before sending it?  I don't have a huge amount of experience with the S1, but you can use the XBee documentation to see what you're actually asking in the outbound request.  Note that the Tx Status of 0x01 lets you know that the packet hasn't arrived on the remote XBee, so you can focus on debugging the wireless communications instead of investigating possible host serial communication failures on the receiver end.

Comment: Glad you were able to debug and isolate the issue, and then figure out the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to read data from the Xbee is just to open the serial port in a separate thread and constantly loop for 0x7E (the start delimiter). That is what I'm doing with my code and it works fine. I used the RxTxSerial library and this tutorial to get it started:
http://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/java-serial-port-trail/
I don't have my code resetting the xbee or having to wait to be able to receive the data properly. If you would like to have a look at my code then I will gladly share and explain it.